# При компиляции старого проекта на новой версии Android API в Delphi XE7 на смартфоне вылетает приложение

Tags: android, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Создавал небольшую программу на Delphi XE7 для Андроид 4.0.3. Работало всё идеально. Затем купил новый смартфон с Андроидом 6.0. И приложение на нем уже при запуске просто вылетало без каких либо ошибок. Решил в Delphi XE7 в SDK Manager обновить все до API 23 (Андроид 6.0). Затем перекомпилировал проект и снова при запуске на смартфоне вылетает и выбрасывает тупо на главный экран. Что не так?

Comment: А если вы создадите новое приложение, оно работает?

Comment: Да новое работает хорошо. Пробовал даже создать новый проект, и скопировать все элементы со старой формы на форму в новом проекте. И все равно вылетает приложение.

Comment: Попробуйте копировать по кускам и определить, в чем же все-таки проблема.

Comment: При удалении Стринггридов, буттонов, едитов приложение запускается.

Comment: Попробуйте изолировать все до 1 едита, например, и потом сравнить содержимое файлов между проектами - dfm, dproj и т.д.